# What are the shards for?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

During various fights with enemies, I pick up shards - so far I have picked up Lucid shards, and Mythril shards, but I have no idea what to do with them.

What are they used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will use them for Synthesis of equipment and items. You can't do this until later. You won't get the ability to do this until

> You get the Green Trinity in Agrabah

Through synthesizing, you'll be able to create the Ultima Weapon, which is the best weapon in the game. But for now, you can just save them for when you get that point.

Comment: Curse my inability to type on this phone! I was too slow in typing out my answer. GameFAQs has [a pretty good item synthesis guide that might help.](http://m.gamefaqs.com/ps2/516587-kingdom-hearts/faqs/19539)